# How to limit the number of rows printed in kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

When using rmarkdown to render pdf document, we can use three options for printing data.frame: default, kable and tibble (see [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#tab:df-print-pdf))

With the default option, it is possible to limit the number of rows printed, with the option: `max.print`

For tibble, we can use: `dplyr.print_max`

I can't find a way to limit the number of rows for `kable`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

`kable` renders the full data frame passed to it as a table in the output document. AFAIK there's no argument that will limit the number of rows. However, you can preselect the number of rows in the output table (for example, `kable(head(dat))` or `kable(dat[1:5, ])`). If you want to avoid having to select the rows each time, you could write a helper function to limit the number of rows printed. For example:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(knitr)
```

```{r}
my_kable = function(x, max.rows=6, ...) {
  kable(x[1:max.rows, ], ...)
}
```

```{r}
my_kable(mtcars, caption="My first caption")
```

```{r}
iris$Sepal.Length = 1000 * iris$Sepal.Length
my_kable(iris, 3, caption="My second caption", format.args=list(big.mark=","))
```
````

[image]

Comment: thank you eipi10. In fact, I use `df_print: kable` option in  `pdf_document:` (knitr header). The idea is to control the max number of rows without altering the code, or the outcome when I run the code (with RStudio). So in my R chunk, I simply put, for example `iris`. The `df_print: kable` option is only used for rendering pdf document.

Comment: @XRSC This highlights how important an [mcve] is. Can you provide one?

Answer (score 1):

A really simple solution is to wrap `kable` around `head`:

```
kable(head(mtcars, n = 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom method for printing data frames like this.
*Adapted from Yihui Xie's explanation [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/opts-render.html)*

````cpp
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r include=FALSE}
knit_print.data.frame <- function(x, ...) {
  head(x, 5) |> 
    knitr::kable() |> 
    paste(collapse = "\n") |>
    knitr::asis_output()
}

registerS3method(
  genname = "knit_print",
  class = "data.frame",
  method = knit_print.data.frame,
  envir = asNamespace("knitr")
)
```

```{r}
iris

tibble::as_tibble(iris)
```
````